# Restoring Windows 10 Task Bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

My task bar and start button in Windows 10 disappeared overnight; there was just a black space under the windows. Windows keys do not bring it up.

I seem to recall on older Windows versions you could use Ctrl-Alt-Del to get the Task Manager up, then use an option in the menus (File -> Run), then enter command.com or something like that and the task bar would reappear.

That didn't work here, neither did switching users (then the windows take the whole screen).

Reboot did work, but does anybody know a trick to avoid logging off/closing programs? Thank you.

Comment: Using the CTRL + ALT + DEL method you used to run a command, could you run `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: Also, does the problem reoccur in a new user account?

Comment: It has only happened once on this install so far, but it is fairly new. It was an uncommon recurring thing on and older Windows version installation I had. Will try your suggestion another time.